# Backup a tree of folders, but print each file individually

Tags: python, python-3.x, tarfile

I am creating a script to backup an entire program with multiple folders, databases and hundred of folders and files. For that I use this code and it works great (slightly editted for SO).

```
import tarfile
import datetime
PATH_PROGRAM = os.getcwd()

# Part 1: Get list of files
files_to_save = []
for file_name in listdir(PATH_PROGRAM):
    if not file_name == "Backups Folder": # Exclude the folder where we store them
        files_to_save.append(file_name)

# Part 2: Get name for new backup file
date_now = str(datetime.datetime.now())[:10]
backupfile = "{0}\\Backups Folder\\{1}.tar.gz".format(PATH_PROGRAM, date_now)

# Part 3: Add all files to new backup
with tarfile.open(backupfile, "w:gz") as tar:
    for file in files_to_save:
        print("Saving: {0}".format(file))
        tar.add("{0}\\{1}".format(PATH_PROGRAM, file))
```

**The problem:**
With this code, my prints just show me the base folder instead of each file, like:

```
Saving: File1.txt
Saving: File2.mp3
Saving: Folder_sounds
Saving: something.json
```

Let's pretend that `folder_sounds` is a folder with thousands of files. The script will take a lot of time (freezing my GUI) while adding up that folder files to the tar file but I don't really know the progress of it because the print is not showing me each file individually. That's the problem.

**What I tried:**

I tried to get the full path of each file at part 1 of my code, however that would add the files to the tarfile without creating folders inside the tarfile or adding the files inside its respective folder. It was a mess because all the files were in the same place.

**Desired solution:**

1: Print each file name as they are being added to the tarfile.
2: Store all the files in the tarfile without breaking the tree of folders where each file belongs.

Comment: any reason you're not putting things in a git repository?

Comment: I never use git or github as I'm self-taught and those places confuse me more than help me.

Comment: Do not put the backup folder inside the directory tree you are backing up. If that is not possible, use tar with `--exclude` option. Then just start  e.g. `tar cvzf /path/to/backupfile.tar.gz /path/to/programdir` and watch its progres (read filenames line by line from standard output). No Python code necessary. The example command is in Linux form.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to do it in python and `tarfile` library, though, as I never use Linux (I don't like it, personal choice is to always stick to windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answering my own question until a better answer is provided:**

```
# Part 1 became a function
def get_all_files_for_backup(self):
    """Returns a Dict"""
    dict_of_diles = {}
    for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(PATH_PROGRAM):
        if not "Backups Folder" in dirpath:  # Exclude this folder
            for filename in filenames:
                if dirpath in dict_of_diles:
                    # If folder exists, append this file to it
                    dict_of_diles[dirpath].append(filename)
                else:
                    # Create a new item in the dict for this folder
                    dict_of_diles[dirpath] = [filename]
    return dict_of_diles

files_to_save = self.get_all_files_for_backup()

# Part 3: We create the tree structure in the tarfile before adding files to it
with tarfile.open(backupfile, "w:gz") as tar:
    for folder, files in files_to_save.items():
        # Create the right tree folders inside the tar file
        relative_folder = folder.replace(PATH_PROGRAM, "")
        if relative_folder.startswith("\\"):
            relative_folder = relative_folder[1:]
            tarfolder = tarfile.TarInfo(relative_folder)
            tarfolder.type = tarfile.DIRTYPE
            tar.addfile(tarfolder)
        # Add the files
        for file in files:
            full_path = os.path.join(folder, file)
            print(full_path)
            # Don't add an arcname if relative folder is none
            if relative_folder == "":
                tar.add(full_path, arcname=file)
            else:
                # Args for tar.add are: Copy from absolute path, Copy to that tar folder.
                tar.add(full_path, arcname="{0}\\{1}".format(relative_folder, file))
```